# Arch Overscan Screen Slanted

Tags: boot, archlinux

Recently I have attempted to install Arch Linux on my Raspberry Pi 3B for a small project. After installation of the OS according to https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3, the text on my monitor was overflowing. I attempted to fix this by editing the FAT32 partition's config.txt file by adding the following lines:

```
overscan_left=10
overscan_right=10
overscan_top=30
overscan_bottom=30
```

However this caused my entire screen to become slanted diagonally, making the text on it completely illegible. I also attempted

```
disable_overscan=1
```

But this simply reverted the system to the original overflowing problem. In a troubleshooting attempt I then tried

```
overflow_left=1
```

This resulted in the entire screen appearing essentially in italics.

I have no clue what is going on here and have as yet been unable to find any documentation online regarding the problem.

Here are my specifications:
Model: Raspberry Pi 3B V1.2
OS: Arch Linux Latest RPi 3 from http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-3-latest.tar.gz
OS Installing From: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Also, I don't know if it's important but in the config.txt file there is also this line (there at the start)

```
enable_uart=1
```

I believe this fixes a RasPi 3 bug in the display (this might affect something??). However, removing this line doesn't seem to change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. Apparently, my (very old) Sony Bravia monitor was the problem. Having tried it on a newer monitor, the whole thing works perfectly.

No settings changes were needed on the Pi. Same cables, different monitor.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.